# Using VNC with DRI3

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, xorg, vnc

While using DRI3 on Xorg on ubuntu 16.04, I can't have any working VNC server working well on my desktop :
I encounter some black or white flashes, some afterglow effect (previous images not displayed anymore showing suddenly).

I've tried x11vnc and x0vncserver, and I observe the same artefacts. I tried different clients on MacOS and windows, and it does not fix the issue.

Does someone succeed into having VNC with Xorg in DRI3 mode ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to use **vinoserver** instead of **x11vnc**.

There is no more artefacts on VNC client side.